# Recieving errors when running server with manage.py

Tags: python, django, cron, cron-task

im trying to run a server on my laptop, when in the console i type 'python manage.py runserver'
i recieve some errors. could it be i need to import some modules i tried 'pip install python-cron' but that didnt work.
the error says:

```
[2020-11-10 09:04:47,241] autoreload: INFO - Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_cron'
```

the cron.py file i have is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import os
import datetime
from crontab import CronTab
#from django_common.helper import send_mail
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
from .models import Photo
from PIL import Image


class PhotoDeleteCronJob(CronJobBase):

    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1



    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'cron.PhotoDeleteCronJob'

    def do(self):
        delet = Photo.objects.all()
        delet.delete()
```

thanks in advance if you need to see any other files just ask.

Comment: did you try pip install `pip install django-cron` ?

Comment: Can you share your installed app from settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps if you missed,

Step 1:
`pip install django-cron`

Step 2:
Open your settings.py and register this in your installed_app
`djnago-cron`

Step 3:
You need to make migrations after installing app in settings.py by
`python manage.py makemigrations djnago-cron`

Step 4:
Than migrate these changes by
`python manage.py migrate`

Step 5:
You are now ready to go and just run server by
`python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

try installing django cron with this

```
pip install django-cron
```

i think you have enabled a virtual environment and then trying to to starting server
many people make this mistake.!!

**you have to reinstall all external libraries that are need for django** (not the fundamental libraries like os math numpy etc.)

also make migrations by this code

```
python manage.py makemigrations django-cron
```

these are silly mistakes